# Excel and VBA formatting without conditionals

Tags: excel, vba

Could someone point me in the right direction with a problem please?
I have 2 ranges of values in an excel sheet, (F3:K44) and (N6:S6).
What I'm trying to achieve is when a user enters numbers in range (N6:S6) I want any duplicates in (F3:K44) to change the background colour.  Conditional formatting will not suffice as there is only 3 options and I need 6.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a cell in `F3:K44` has a match in any cell in `N6:S6` then you could change the conditional formatting to a formula to find a match, and use `match()` formula in there.

Create a new rule on `F3` and choose "Use a Formula to determine which cells to format".

In there, enter

```
=MATCH(F3,$N$6:$S$6,0)>0
```

Save that and copy the formatting through `F3:N44` and you'll be good to go.

That `MATCH()` formula will look in the second Parameter's range for the First Parameter's value. The `0` in the Third Parameter tells it to only do an exact match (otherwise you'll get some unexpected matching).

An example of this in action:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply and this looks exactly what I need, but alas, I can't get this to work. Perhaps it's my version of excel as it's only the 2003 version? I did work out a conditional format version myself but my version of excel only allows for 3 conditional formats.                                                                                                     I don't get the option you mention 'and choose "Use a Formula to determine which cells to format"'. I only have 'Cell value is' and 'Formula is'

Comment: That would definitely be a version thing. Use the "Formula Is" option and stick that same formula in. It should work fine there.

Comment: I selected my range (F3:K44) first, then pasted your formula in and bingo. I didn't have to copy the formula as you suggested, just select the range and create the conditional format. Nice one, thank you very much.